# Stop submitted lines of code from running

Tags: r, queue, rstudio

I'm running a long R script, which takes 2 or 3 days to finish. I accidentally run another script, which, if it works as R usually does, will go in some queue and R will run it as soon as the first script is over. I need to stop that, as it would compromise the results from the first script. Is there a visible queue or any other way to stop R from running some code?

I'm working on an interactive session in R studio, on windows 10.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Where is this queue, on what OS and running with which commands/packages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with where is the queue?
For the rest I edited. I'm working on windows, commands and packages are many, I run by mistake a full script

Comment: Are you just running some large script or scheduled different scripts? I personally don't get whath `queue` refers to here. For instance, one could think of scheduled jobs via scheduler or cron but not sure if that's what you've done.

Comment: If you are simply in R and ran a script, and then ran another script, the second will run and to my knowledge there is nothing you can do about it. There is no spot where you can see a list of code waiting to run and cancel it.

Comment: @Adam yes that's simply what happened. Thank you for you answer

Comment: It's difficult to help with so little information, and in a way that will be useful for other users in the future. You'll have better luck getting answers if you add detail to the question rather than telling us it's urgent

Comment: @camille I know the guidelines and they don't seem to apply. It has nothing to do with what I'm running. It's 1000 lines of code of all sorts. It's a question about R, and about how to stop R from running the next line of code if you ran more at once.

Comment: The edit makes it pretty clear to me what you are asking. I can see this being helpful to somebody else in a similar situation. I think a title edit to "Stop submitted lines of code from running" or something would clean that up a bit too. I don't know if that still would be considered off topic without a specific code question.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion for the title. Thank you for your answers and for your kindness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're running in console (or interactive session in R studio, that's undetermined from your question) and that what you did was sourcing a script/pasting code and while it was running pasting another chunck of code:

What is ongoing is that you pushed data into R process input stream, it's a buffered input, so it will run each line once the previous line call has ended and free the process.

There's no easy way to play with an input buffer, that's R internal input/output system and mostly it's the Operating system which have those information in cache for now.

Asking R itself is not possible as it already has this buffer to read, any new command would go after.

**Last chance thing**: If you can spot your another chunck of code starting in your console, you can try pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to stop the code running.

You may try messing with the process buffers with [procexp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) but there's a fair chance to just make your R session segfault anyway.

To avoid that in the future, use scripts and run them on the command line separately with [Rscript](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rscript) (present in R bin directory under windows too despite the link pointing to a linux manpage).
This would create one session per script and allow to kill them independently. That said if they both write to the same place (database, a file would create an error if accessed by two process) that won't prevent data corruption.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I thought some sort of queue existed and could be modified but apparently that's not the case. I'll try the last chance thing if by any chance R finishes running the first script while I'm still awake.
Thanks for the final suggestion, that's actually what I'm doing (I have 10 sessions open) but I got distracted and sent the script to a busy session.

Comment: @Antonio That's why I speak about launching different process with RScript, that way you can not paste new input in the process and mess the results, for long running things that helps "protecting" them.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing OP has below problem:

```
# my big code, running for a long time
Sys.sleep(10); print("hello 1")

# other big code I dropped in console while R was still busy with above code
print("hello 2")
```

If this is the case, I don't think it is possible to stop the 2nd process from running.